# Kohana 3 : $_GET shows URI route (controller/method) instead of the $_GET params

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

Im in /order/test

When I try to /order/test?lala=test&baba=test

```
public function action_test(){
echo var_dump($_GET);
}
```

It should output lala=test&baba=test in the var_dump(), but instead it gives me:

```
array(1) { ["order/test"]=> string(0) "" }
```

Why has this happend? How can i fix this?

This is my htaccess:

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [F,L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} ^.+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(gif|jpe?g|png|pdf)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php?$0 [PT,L]
```

Comment: What's in your `.htaccess`? PS: in kohana you need to use Request object rather than superglobals to access request parameters

Comment: @zerkms I updated question with my access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your rewrite rule to

```
RewriteRule .* index.php?$0 [PT,L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have in original .htaccess:

```
# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

Also don't use $_GET, but

```
$this->request->query()
```

instead for HMVC applications.